# jquery plugin does not apply for an element inside a modal window

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I'm using [chosen-select](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) plugin to get more of a `<select>` it works fine inside the main page, but when I use it inside a modal window that's provided by UIKit, it does not work. 
Here is the code:

Initialize the plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var config = {
        '.chosen-select': {},
        '.chosen-select-no-results': { no_results_text: 'nothing found!' }
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
        $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
});
```

And every `<select>` that has `.chosen-select` class is affected by the plugin.

Here is the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/xFv4W/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `.chosen-select` class and applying `.chosen()` after loading modal fixed it.
Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/xFv4W/13/